# TypeScript Error: invalid new expression

Tags: typescript

This is my class in typescript language:

```
export interface ILogger {
    bla bla
}

export class Logger implements ILogger {

   bla bla
}

export var logger: ILogger = new Logger();
```

and when I use this class like this:

```
logger: logger = new logger();
```

I get this error:

> Invalid 'New' Expression

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class *instance* is not newable (`new logger`). Nor is it a valid *type* (`:logger`). Sample

```
class Logger {
}

var logger = new Logger();

var logger2: logger = new logger(); // 2 errors
```

Fix. Something you already did for `logger`. Do it again:

```
class Logger {
}

var logger = new Logger();

var logger2: Logger = new Logger();
```

Answer (score 1):

I create instance of class like this -

say **logger.ts**

```
export interface ILogger {
    bla bla
}

export class Logger implements ILogger {

   bla bla
}

export function getInstance() {
    var instance = new Logger();
    return instance;
}
```

and then, wherever you require logger -

```
import logger = require('./logger');
var mylogger = logger.getInstance();
```

Comment: getInstance usually symbolizes a singleton pattern, not a factory pattern.

Comment: What does it means Ingo?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Basarat - if you want a `new` one, you should create a `new Logger()` - but if you are trying to use the instance of a logger you exported, you can simply use that without instantiating it, because you already did that here...

```
export var logger: ILogger = new Logger();
```

So you can use it straight out of the box (you haven't supplied the implementation details, so I've made them up here)...

```
// not logger: logger = new logger(); - just use it...
logger.methodName();
```